# NetworkStream doesn't always send data unless I Thread.Sleep() before closing the NetworkStream. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm having problems sending a very small piece of data (a date) to another TcpClient running on the same computer.

In the code below you will see that it sleeps before closing the NetworkStream. If I remove the `Sleep` it causes an intermittent problem where the data doesn't turn up at the other end.

**Am I doing something wrong here?**

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, _tcpServerPort));
    NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

    byte[] buffer = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(theDateObject.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));                            
    clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    clientStream.Flush();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Remove this line and the data may not arrive at the other end
    clientStream.Close();
}
```

Some other information:

- On some computers you can remove the `Sleep` without it causing a problem (slower computers perhaps?)
- I've tried closing the NetworkStream with `Close(int timeout)` (instead of sleeping) but that didn't help.
- The 1000 millisecond value is arbitrary - I suspect that other values would work too. The question is: why is it required in the first place?

Comment: Just to check - are you expecting that all of the data will arrive in a single call to `Read` at the other end? Because that's not a guarantee with TCP sockets.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I am. But I believe that the code at the other end would error if the full message was not received on the first read (as it tries to DateTime.Parse() the message straight away). I have not seen any exceptions thrown at the other end.

Comment: @shambulator - no, it's relevant even if you're using the stream. If you're using this, rather than a higher level abstraction (e.g. WCF, web services, etc) then you're responsible for reconstructing messages yourself. Note the documentation for [`NetworkStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx): "The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Apologies, I misread your first comment to be about writing all available data, which is why I hastily deleted mine :P

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this is unlikely to be the issue? Given that I try to DateTime.Parse() what I receive from my first (and only) NetworkStream.Read()?

Comment: I don't think it's *the* issue, but I wanted to make sure that you're aware of it - people tend to assume (without reading the documentation) that one call of `Write` will be matched by one call to `Read` at the other end.

Answer (score 1):

Calling close with a timeout on a NetworkStream means that the network stream will stay open in the background for X time to allow remaining data to be sent. In the background is important to note since your code is not blocked by this. Because you encapsulate the tcpClient in a using statement, the client and internally the NetworkStream will be disposed directly after your call to close. Sleep in this case works since it allows the data to be sent out and blocks your method in the meantime to prevent it from forcefully disposing of its resources.

A cleaner solution would be to set an active LingerState on the TcpClient with a long enough timeout. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.lingerstate.aspx

Comment: What you say makes sense. But if that is the case, then how are you supposed to know when it's safe to close a TcpClient? EDIT: Seen your edit with link to LingerState. That looks like it could be a solution and I'll definitely try that.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have worked. One of my users is still having intermittent problems where the data does not arrive at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

If your receive queue is not empty (you got data in your receive buffer from the server that you haven't read, disposing the Socket (Client) sends a TCP RST (Resets the connection)) and the data in the send buffer is discarded i.e if not already sent lost, otherwise it waits till the send buffer is empty and then terminates the tcp connection.

One workaround is to close the send channel:

```
    client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)
    clientStream.Close();
}
```

before closing the client (instead of thread.sleep), in this case the conneciton is not reset.

Also .Flush() does nothing on a networkstream.

see: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/JavaSockets/RecvQClose.pdf