# Close unmanaged resources when Subscription end in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm writing data to the network from Rx. Naturally I use `Finally` to close my stream when the subscription end. This works cleanly both on `OnError()` and `OnComplete()`. Rx will run `OnNext()`  ... `OnNext()`, `OnComplete()`, `Finally()` in sequence.

However, sometimes I want to terminate the sequence early, to do so I use `Dispose()`. Somehow `Finally()` is now ran in parallel with the last `OnNext()` call, resulting in a Exceptions when still writing to the stream in `OnNext()`, as well as incomplete writes.

My subscription looks roughly like this:

```
NetworkStream stm = client.GetStream();
IDisposable disp = obs
    .Finally(() => {
        client.Close();
    })
    .Subscribe(d => {
        client.GetStream().Write(d.a, 0, d.a.Lenght);
        client.GetStream().Write(d.b, 0, d.b.Lenght);
    } () => {
        client.GetStream().Write(something(), 0, 1);
    });
Thread.sleep(1000);
disp.Dispose();
```

I've also tried the alternative, `CancellationToken`.

How can I cancel my subscription properly? I dont mind if it skips `OnComplete()`, as long as `Finally()` still runs. However, running `Finally()` in parallel is problematic.

I also have the feeling there should be a better way to manage resources by moving the declaration into the sequence, that would be a even better solution.

Edit: The following code displays the problem more clearly. I would hope it always prints true, instead, it gives false more often than not, indicating Dispose end before the last `OnNext` does.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try finally");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Finally();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Try using");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Using();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Try using2");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Using2();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Using2()
        {
            bool b = true, c = true, d;
            var dis = Disposable.Create(() => c = b);
            IDisposable obDis = Observable.Using(
                () => dis,
                _ => Observable.Create<Unit>(obs=>
                    Observable.Generate(0,
                    i => i < 1000,
                    i => i + 1,
                    i => i,
                    i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
                ).Subscribe(__ => { b = false; Thread.Sleep(100); b = true; })))
                .Subscribe();
            Thread.Sleep(15);
            obDis.Dispose();
            d = b;
            Thread.Sleep(101);
            Console.WriteLine("OnDispose: {1,5} After: {2,5} Sleep: {0,5}", b, c, d);
        }

        private static void Using()
        {
            bool b = true, c = true, d;
            var dis = Disposable.Create(() => c = b);
            IDisposable obDis = Observable.Using(
                () => dis,
                _ => Observable.Generate(0,
                    i => i < 1000,
                    i => i + 1,
                    i => i,
                    i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
                )).Subscribe(_ => { b = false; Thread.Sleep(100); b = true; });
            Thread.Sleep(15);
            obDis.Dispose();
            d = b;
            Thread.Sleep(101);
            Console.WriteLine("OnDispose: {1,5} After: {2,5} Sleep: {0,5}", b, c, d);
        }

        private static void Finally()
        {
            bool b = true, c = true, d;
            IDisposable obDis = Observable.Generate(0,
                i => i < 1000,
                i => i + 1,
                i => i,
                _ => DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1)
                )
                .Finally(() => c = b)
                .Subscribe(_ => { b = false; Thread.Sleep(100); b = true; });
            Thread.Sleep(15);
            obDis.Dispose();
            d = b;
            Thread.Sleep(101);
            Console.WriteLine("OnDispose: {1,5} After: {2,5} Sleep: {0,5}", b, c, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Finally` is most probably not what you want. It will not dispose your resource when you cancel the subscription. Rather, it will behave like a normal `finally` block in C#, that is, it will guarantee that some code is executed whether or not the code in its corresponding `try`-block threw an exception. Furthermore, given [this question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfafc584-fd9d-45b0-8a53-354b53813a1a/observablefinally-not-executing?forum=rx), your code in `Finally` might not even execute in every circumstance since your subscription does not specify an Error-handler.

What you probably want is `Using`:

```
IDisposable disp = Observable
    .Using(
        () => Disposable.Create(() => client.Close),
        _ => obs)
    .Subscribe(....);
```

`Using` takes care that a resource is properly disposed whenever the observable terminates or the subscription is cancelled.

Assuming `client` is a TcpClient, it becomes even simpler:

```
IDisposable disp = Observable
    .Using(
        () => client),
        _ => obs)
    .Subscribe(....);
```

I expect that calls to `OnNext` will not overlap with closing the client, even when unsubsribing early, but I have not tested this.

One last thing: Beware of closing over outer variables like `stm` in your example. It is safer to always work with locals. The complete rewriting as I would try it goes like this:

```
IDisposable disp = Observable.Using(
    () => client,
    _ => Observable.Using(
         () => client.GetStream(),
         stream => Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => obs
             .Subscribe(
                 d => {
                     stream.Write(d.a, 0, d.a.Lenght);
                     stream.Write(d.b, 0, d.b.Lenght);
                 },
                 () => {
                     stream.Write(something(), 0, 1);
                 }))))
    .Subscribe();
```

Comment: Actually `Finally` does run on errors, I think that bug has been fixed since 2012. Anyway, the reset of your answer looks promising, I had the feeling `Observable.Using` should fit, but I couldn't figure out how yet. `client` indeed is a `TcpClient`, so I'm going to give that a go.

Comment: Btw, your last example doesn't compile. There is a bracket error on the second line, and something wrong with `Observable.Create` that I cant fix.

Comment: Should be fixed. Try again.

Comment: `OnNext` calls do **not** overlap. That's part of the behaviour contract for Rx.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, `OnNext` and `OnComplete` do not overlap. `Finally` however, completely unexpected, does. (But that's not against any Rx contract.)

Comment: @Dorus - What `finally`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Read the question.... Calls can overlap with `OnNext`, the thing not tested here is if they overlap with `Using`.

Comment: @Dorus - Ah, gotcha. That sounds like a bug in Rx. A serious one.

Comment: Tried to `Using` solution, same result :-( I guess I will have to cook up my own variant of Finally to get around this....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have simply made an incorrect assumption about how `NetworkStream` operates.

`NetworkStream.Write` and `TcpClient.Close` don't necessarily wait for the client to read the data. (Furthermore, `NetworkStream.Flush` doesn't do anything).

When you call `Close` you are probably shutting the socket before the client has read everything.

Have a look at this related question: [NetworkStream doesn't always send data unless I Thread.Sleep() before closing the NetworkStream. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969994/networkstream-doesnt-always-send-data-unless-i-thread-sleep-before-closing-th)

That page variously mentions things like using the overload of `Close` that accepts a timeout, or specifying a `LingerOption` - but best is either sending a `Shutdown` or to have a higher level messaging abstraction where the client acknowledges your message with a reply of it's own.